# How to convert String encoded in windows-1250/Cp1250 to utf-8?

Tags: java, string

As title say ...
I read content from htto response

```
 

    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String cw = IOUtils.toString(is);
    byte[] b = cw.getBytes("Cp1250");
    String x = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(b);
    String content = new String(b, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(content);
```

I have tried plenty of variations. I am little confused about what are correct encoding constants used as strings. windows-1250 or Cp1250. UTF-8 or utf-8 or utf8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to think that a `String` object has an encoding. That's not correct. An encoding is used as part of the translation from binary data (a `byte[]` or `InputStream`) to text data (a `String` or `char[]` etc).

It's not clear what `IOUtils.toString` is doing, but it's almost certainly losing data or at least handling it inappropriately. If your data is originally in Windows-1250, then you should use an `InputStreamReader` wrapping the `InputStream`, specifying the charset in the `InputStreamReader` constructor call.

It's not clear where UTF-8 comes in - you might want to *write out* the data in UTF-8 afterwards, but the result of that would be `byte[]`, not a string.

Comment: Technically speaking, `java.lang.String` has an Encoding: UTF-16.

Answer (score 6):

You're converting backwards.  You need to get the input data as a `byte` array and then use `String(byteArray, "Cp1250")` to create the String object.  Then if you want UTF-8, use `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding have a canonical (unique) name and other varying names, and that case-insensitive. For instance "UTF-8" is the canonical name, but some java versions back it was "UTF8"; it got written more to the common usage. The same for "Windows-1250," which you might see also in HTML pages. "Cp1250" (Code-Page) is a java internal name.

**In java byte[] is binary data, String (internally Unicode) is text.**
Conversion between both needs an encoding, often optional though, taking the operating system default.

byte, InputStream, OutputStream <-> String, char, Reader, Writer

```
String cw = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8"); // InputStream is binary gives byte[], hence give encoding
byte[] b = cw.getBytes("Cp1250");
String x = new String(b, "Cp1250");
String content = s;

System.out.println(content);
```

To allow this universal (qua encoding) String, String internally uses char, UTF-16.
String constants are stored in the .class file as UTF-8 (more compact).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Apache Commons IO, use [one of the methods that specifies an encoding](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String cw = IOUtils.toString(is, "windows-1250");
```

All strings are implicitly UTF-16 in Java. Other encodings are generally represented using byte arrays.

Answer (score -1):

I see better to use Scanner for reading in different charsets.

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileOrPath);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, "cp1250");
    String out = scanner.next();
```

And method `next()` returns `String` value in charset of application.

Tested on "czech language" from "cp1250" to "UTF-8".